# OBS Crashes when clicking on Settings

Tags: obs-studio

When I click on the settings button OBS crashes. Sometimes it won't crash, until I click something on the settings page.

Here is a log file: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2faab5dcbba087030480

Comment: I have the same problem, OBS is very unstable on 16.04 (64Bit). Crashes whenever I try to change settings. Log file here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/88d1d92a8a9a9f11bc1eef81c941c0d5